# In ActiveRecord, how to get the name of primary key(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

With `DataMapper` i can iterate through properties and select one(s) of type `Serial`.

Any straightforward way to do this in `ActiveRecord`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call `YourModel.arel_table.primary_key.name`.  Or better yet, `YourModel.primary_key`.

Answer (score 11):

`Model.primary_key` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using customised primary keys for your models? otherwise `id` is always the primary key.